# Does there exist a language with the characteristic of storing variables in persistent storage?

Tags: programming-languages

I had this idea this morning, and was thinking about how to implement it when it occurred to me somebody has probably already done this. I searched but found nothing, here's my idea:

In short, all variable storage is stored in persistent storage. I don't mean battery backed up RAM. I mean more like a database.

To use common technologies to explain what I mean: Lets say you were to use an SQL database for this persistent storage. An array/list would be stored as a table with one column. An ordered list would be stored as two columns with the first being a sequence number. A hash would be a table with two columns, the first being the key, the second being the value. All simple stuff. But what I'm getting at is that you could do large data moving/calculating/reporting operations with native language constructs without all that mucking about in hyper... I mean without all that SQL and loading data from the database.
I was thinking sort of like the way you can do matrix math in APL. It would be native to the language and all the underpinning storage would just work. And in reality it would use a record manager more than a SQL database. That was just to explain.

Of course this would be horribly slow, but solid state disk is getting bigger faster and cheaper, so this might not be as unwieldy as it might first seem.

Anyway, is this a novel idea or has somebody done this before?

Comment: Python and Pickle (but with a database)?

Comment: How persistent do you want it? Still there when the power is cycled? The reason languages don't do this is because of need and speed. If you need something to remain (like in a database), you write it there, but writing to a database is much slower than writing to memory. Most variables are not needed that long, so languages just store to memory and have calls to write to database.

Comment: You might look deeply into http://tunes.org/ for references. And it could also be an operating system issue http://www.coyotos.org/ or Kangaroo. Your idea is not main-stram, but I did read things about it. And http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/ could be a more appropriate place to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MUMPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUMPS) has something like that.

> Database interaction is transparently built into the language. The MUMPS language provides a hierarchical database made up of persistent sparse arrays, which is implicitly “opened” for every MUMPS application. All variable names prefixed with the caret character (“`^`”) use permanent (instead of RAM) storage, will maintain their values after the application exits, and will be visible to (and modifiable by) other running applications.

Of course, it’s explicit—thus not applied to all variables—but still automatic.

Comment: Sounds kinda like what I'm talking about. I was really thinking more of a paradigm shift where you (the program) lives in the context of the huge data store, not that it be a feature of the language. I'm thinking of all the times, I do sql, get data from the response, then format it for web display or report output or whatever. Wouldn't it just be nice to be able to say "printf ("%s\t%s\n", data1[i], data2[i++]);" and there's no selecting, there's no loading into arrays, there's just data output.

Comment: So I was reading the wikipedia article on mumps and it sounds like they were going for the same thing. Thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 0):

How persistent are you talking?  The [localStorage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/) API works well (persists across browser tabs and sessions) so long as you know users can choose to clear it out. Your question sounds eerily like WebKit [client-side database storage](http://www.webkit.org/blog/126/webkit-does-html5-client-side-database-storage/) though.

Answer (score -1):

Well, to point out the obvious, there is SQL.